# How to call a div inside another component which is common in all pages only to a certain page and make that div hidden from other pages?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a common component that is common to all other components. Inside that I added a slider in that portion, which is applicable to only one component. So how can make that particular div inside a component invisible for all other components. When Iam setting isVisible as true in .ts file its visible in all other components also. How can I make it visible in only one page

```
<div class="mycontainer" *ngIf="isVisible">
 <div class="border1"></div>
  <div class="toggle1">
   <mat-slide-toggle> New Toggle</mat-slide-toggle>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set an `@input` inside your `.ts` file and set it to false:

```
@Input() isVisible = false;
```

and only at this specific time give it a true value

```
<your-component [isVisible]="true"></your-component>
```

in the all the others you don't need to add it, because it's have is default value

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

Let `isVisible` be an input with a default value

`@Input() isVisible = false`

and then for that particular page set `[isVisible]="true"`

### Option 2

Explore angular's content projection.

Adding `<ng-content></ng-content>` to the component template you can project content via

```
<my-component>
  ... etc
  <mat-slide-toggle> New Toggle</mat-slide-toggle>
</my-component>
```